# Oracle 11g Get distinct of multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm having a table with images and one table with image info (for example: size).

```
**TABLE `images`**
id | name  | path | status       | changedate
---------------------------------------------
1  | 1.tif | xxx/ | corrected    | 2013/03/13
2  | 1.tif | zzz/ | uncorrected  | 2013/03/13
3  | 1.tif | yyy/ | corrected    | 2013/03/14
4  | 2.tif | zzz/ | correct      | 2013/03/29

**TABLE `imageinfo`** 
imageid | size
------------------
1       | 100x200
2       | 100x200
3       | 100x200
4       | 127x127
```

For info: It is possible that there are more than 1 image with the same name.

I want to get the fields `name`, `size`, `status` and `changedate` of the images ordered by the `name`, `status` and `changedate` (ordered in this order).

As you can see its possible that there are more than 1 image with the same name. I only want  one row per `name`, the first row if there are duplicate `name` images.

What I already have:

```
SELECT 
  name,
  size,
  status,
  changedate
FROM images
JOIN imageinfo ON images.id = imageinfo.imageid
ORDER BY
  name, 
  status,
  changedate
```

**Executed output:**

```
3 | 1.tif | 100x200 | corrected   | 2013/03/14
1 | 1.tif | 100x200  | corrected   | 2013/03/13
2 | 1.tif | 100x200 | uncorrected | 2013/03/13
4 | 2.tif | 127x127 | correct     | 2013/03/29
```

**Required output:**

```
3 | 1.tif | 100x200 | corrected   | 2013/03/14
4 | 2.tif | 127x127 | correct     | 2013/03/29
```

A distinct wont work here, thats what I already figured out.
But how to do this in Oracle?

Comment: Can you please add your executed output as well ?

Comment: How are you going to identify the correct image size, when the image `1.tif` is associated with 3 different sizes?

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: added executed and expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can identify the first row using `row_number` and then use that to filter out the duplicates:

```
select name, size, status, changedate
from (SELECT name, size, status, changedate,
             row_number() over (partition by i.name order by i.changedate desc) as seqnum
      FROM images i JOIN
           imageinfo ii
           ON i.id = ii.imageid
     ) i
where seqnum = 1
order by name, status, changedate;
```

EDIT:

The `row_number()` function generates a sequence of integers starting with 1 for groups of rows.  The groups of rows are defined by the `partition by` clause.  So, in this case, each set of rows with the same `i.name` will re-start the numbering.  The order of the integers is based on the `order by` clause.  So, in this case, the most recent change date within each group gets a value of `1` and so on.

Comment: `partition by i.name order by i.changedate desc` as per user's new requirement, and you are done!

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  Getting the first occurrence seemed odd, usually the most recent is more interesting.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and @MaheshwaranRavisankar Shouldn't it be `order by status, changedate` in the partition by clause

Comment: Thanks for your help, can u explain what 'over' and 'partition' means herefor?

Comment: @frgtv10 apply row number a temp sequence number OVER the column name